# JavaScript opacity of a table element

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax

I'm a beginner in JavaScript and AJAX!

I have a JavaScript code that updates an HTML table element (contained in a div) using AJAX when the state of a select element changes.
That part works perfectly.

On the other hand, I can't get an opacity animation to the update to work.
Chrome's JavaScript console tells me :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined

at line 2 of the JavaScript code.

Here's my JavaScript code :

```
function fadeIn(objectToFade) {
    objectToFade.style.opacity = parseFloat(objectToFade.style.opacity) + 0.1;

    if ( objectToFade.style.opacity < 1 ) {
        setTimeout(function() { fadeIn(objectToFade); }, 50);
    }
}

function fadeOut(objectToFade) {
    objectToFade.style.opacity = parseFloat(objectToFade.style.opacity) - 0.1;

    if ( objectToFade.style.opacity > 0.2 ) {
        setTimeout(function() { fadeOut(objectToFade); }, 50);
    }
}

function changeClient(client) {

    var clientTableDiv = document.getElementById("clientTable");
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    fadeOut(document.getElementById("MetricsStatsByClient"));

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            clientTableDiv.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            fadeIn(document.getElementById("MetricsStatsByClient"));
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET","functions.php?fct=cc&client=" + client, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

It seems the "style" property is not recognized.
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

**EDIT 1**

After fixing the parameters of the recursive calls, I get NaN (Not a Number) while running this in the changeClient function :

```
alert(parseFloat(document.getElementById("MetricsStatsByClient").style.opacity));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not passing in the object reference so `objectToFade` is undefined.

```
setTimeout(fadeIn, 50);
```

so you need to pass it along

```
setTimeout(function() { fadeIn(objectToFade); }, 50);
```

Same thing with your `fadeOut` also.

Comment: That won't help, will it? haha. I fixed it, now I get a NaN on opacity. See EDIT 1 in OP

Comment: Well does it have a opacity value to start? `console.log(document.getElementById("MetricsStatsByClient").style.opacity);`

Comment: No, it does not. I assumed there was a default value but your code displays... nothing!
Thanks for the hint, I will work on this.

Comment: It works! My AJAX request is too fast to display the animation but I tested it separately and I have a nice fluid fade. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

When you pass `fadeOut`/`fadeIn` to the `setTimeout` calls, you do not specify the element parameter it is expecting:

```
if ( objectToFade.style.opacity < 1 ) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        fadeIn(objectToFade);
    }, 50);
}
```

Comment: That won't help, will it? haha.
I fixed it, now I get a NaN on opacity.
See EDIT 1 in OP.